# How can I listen for external keyboard key presses in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, usb

I have an external USB device that acts as a wired keyboard and just streams out keypresses as data. 
And I have connected it to my Android and it does function as a keyboard when any input field is focused.

But what I need is a way to listen for the data coming from the external device only and intercept it so as to be buffered and parsed by the activity (while the activity is in the foreground!!).

My question is:

- Is it possible to listen for external USB keyboard input as a
  separate input and store the data?
- Also is it possible to listen to multiple external keyboards as
  separate inputs and store the data of each individually?

Thank you very much for any assistance.